# Responsive Image Map-Plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemap

I have some problems to create responsive image maps with Matt Stows jQuery Plugin. I followed all the advices, but the image maps are still not responsive. I hope you can help. These are the instructions (Full page: https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps):

1. If possible, add correct, unitless width and height attributes to your image map images. You can override these in CSS to make them responsive.
2. Add a link to jQuery in your page, preferably at the bottom just
   before the closing `</body>`
3. After jQuery, either in a  block or a separate file, call:

   `$('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();`

That's my code, I set a fixed width and height which is overwritten in CSS.

```
<div class="banners">
    <img src="wcf/images/blueTemptation/logo2.jpg" style="width: 980px; height: 80px; display:block;" alt="banner-x" usemap="#banner-y" />
    <map name="banner-y"><area shape="rect" coords="560,1,765,79" href="http://www.filmfutter.com/" alt="Kgergrfr" title="Filmfutter Startseite">
</div>
```

at the bottom of my php I placed this:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/master/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
    });
</script>
```

In case you wonder, I changed the script source to a URL because I wasn't sure about the right path on my server, but that should not be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

So, I did not manage the plugin to get working and I still wonder because obviously I did nothing wrong, but I used another plugin instead, and finally it works properly. In case some others have the same issues, David Bradshaw's library does exactly what I want and resizes image maps the way they should: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/imagemap-resizer

Comment: Hi slurm, It would be great help if you please share the source code of your example in stackblitz

I am trying the same but getting issue like imageMapResize() is not defined
 $('map').imageMapResize();

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it turns out that I was using JQuery v1.8.3, when I updated it to JQuery v1.9, that seemed to do the trick.

Maybe it's a JQuery versioning problem?

Answer (score 0):

I clone the repo as my submodules then it works. I guess the model wasn't designed as kind of CDN that we can use it as URl loading to our HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!